# PHImageManager requestImage Crashing

Tags: ios, ios14, phimagemanager

anyone has any idea what could cause a crash in request Image. I have this symbolicated crash but no idea.
I'm just trying to get the data of a photo after using the image picker. One million thanks if you have!
The problem has been found in the review of my app but I'm not able to reproduce it :(

EDit: I have Added more information about the crash log

```html
{"app_name":"VideoLUT","timestamp":"2020-10-12 16:50:59.00 -0700","app_version":"1.06","slice_uuid":"37a6afee-cc6e-3e64-8d33-4bac9759f096","adam_id":1532861990,"build_version":"15","platform":2,"bundleID":"com.malatok.tonebox","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 14.0.1 (18A393)","incident_id":"0DB9EFD3-B359-4587-AD4D-E8B83B1A398D","name":"VideoLUT"}
Incident Identifier: 0DB9EFD3-B359-4587-AD4D-E8B83B1A398D
CrashReporter Key:   8f4684b617f51ed34d09ed52c6b1a1160a43773c
Hardware Model:      iPad11,3
Process:             VideoLUT [1986]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/444CE516-B292-4EA9-A0AD-649F85479289/VideoLUT.app/VideoLUT
Identifier:          com.videolut
Version:             15 (1.06)
AppStoreTools:       12A7207
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]



Date/Time:           2020-10-12 16:50:59.0271 -0700
Launch Time:         2020-10-12 13:47:32.6334 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.0.1 (18A393)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1938eb5ac __exceptionPreprocess + 220
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1a796542c objc_exception_throw + 59
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1937f41b4 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 99
3   Foundation                      0x194b527bc -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 131
4   Photos                          0x1a3fe7390 +[PHImageManagerRequestTracer registerRequestID:withAssetUUID:] + 287
5   Photos                          0x1a40626cc -[PHImageManager runRequestWithContext:] + 683
6   Photos                          0x1a4061900 -[PHImageManager requestImageDataAndOrientationForAsset:options:resultHandler:] + 995
7   VideoLUT                        0x1009158d8 -[ProjectManager importPhoto13:dismiss:] + 465112 (ProjectManager.m:195)
8   VideoLUT                        0x100914828 -[ProjectManager createProjectWithAsset:uti:] + 460840 (ProjectManager.m:0)
9   VideoLUT                        0x1009d7eb4 __74-[HomeViewController imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:]_block_invoke + 1261236 (HomeViewController.m:347)
10  UIKitCore                       0x1959f4df0 -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 1019
11  UIKitCore                       0x1959ff25c -[_UICurrentContextPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 43
12  UIKitCore                       0x1959f9540 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke.528 + 211
13  UIKitCore                       0x195b3477c -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 111
14  UIKitCore                       0x1966f0260 -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] + 243
15  UIKitCore                       0x1966eff0c -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 1135
16  UIKitCore                       0x196726ca8 -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 723
17  UIKitCore                       0x1966f9f48 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 247
18  UIKitCore                       0x1966fa47c -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 247
19  UIKitCore                       0x1966fa5e0 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 603
20  QuartzCore                      0x196c51cb4 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks+ 1510580 (void*) + 279
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x1934e9ac8 _dispatch_client_callout + 19
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x1934f704c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 835
23  CoreFoundation                  0x1938681e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 15
24  CoreFoundation                  0x1938623b4 __CFRunLoopRun + 2507
25  CoreFoundation                  0x1938614bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 599
26  GraphicsServices                0x1aa2e6820 GSEventRunModal + 163
27  UIKitCore                       0x196205734 -[UIApplication _run] + 1071
28  UIKitCore                       0x19620ae10 UIApplicationMain + 167
29  VideoLUT                        0x100931674 main + 579188 (main.m:14)
30  libdyld.dylib                   0x193528e60 start + 3


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bf1a998c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001da1c3c74 pthread_kill + 272
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019c9edbb4 abort + 104
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a7a64e24 __cxxabiv1::__aligned_malloc_with_fallback+ 65060 (unsigned long) + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a7a56434 demangling_unexpected_handler+ 5172 () + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a7965710 _objc_terminate+ 42768 () + 132
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a7a642a8 std::__terminate(void (*)+ 62120 ()) + 20
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a7a64234 std::terminate+ 62004 () + 44
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001934e9adc _dispatch_client_callout + 40
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001934f704c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 836
10  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001938681e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001938623b4 __CFRunLoopRun + 2508
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001938614bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
13  GraphicsServices                0x00000001aa2e6820 GSEventRunModal + 164
14  UIKitCore                       0x0000000196205734 -[UIApplication _run] + 1072
15  UIKitCore                       0x000000019620ae10 UIApplicationMain + 168
16  VideoLUT                        0x0000000100931674 main + 579188 (main.m:14)
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000193528e60 start + 4

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bf185dd0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bf185184 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000193867cf8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 380
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000193861ea8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1216
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001938614bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   Foundation                      0x0000000194adee30 -[NSRunLoop+ 32304 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232
6   Foundation                      0x0000000194aded08 -[NSRunLoop+ 32008 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 92
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001962b5e94 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 516
8   Foundation                      0x0000000194c490f0 __NSThread__start__ + 864
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001da1c2ca8 _pthread_start + 320
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001da1cb788 thread_start + 8

Thread 2 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bf185dd0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bf185184 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000193867cf8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 380
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000193861ea8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1216
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001938614bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   AudioSession                    0x000000019b1032ac GenericRunLoopThread::Entry+ 53932 (void*) + 164
6   AudioSession                    0x000000019b105390 CAPThread::Entry+ 62352 (CAPThread*) + 92
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001da1c2ca8 _pthread_start + 320
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001da1cb788 thread_start + 8

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001da1cb774 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001da1cb774 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001da1cb774 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bf185e0c semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001934ea018 _dispatch_sema4_wait + 28
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001934ea6b0 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 132
3   UIKitCore                       0x000000019661b51c __69+[_UIAsyncInvocationObserver whenInvocationsCompleteForObservers:do:]_block_invoke_2 + 72
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001934e7fd0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001934e9ac8 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001934eca10 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 692
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001934fa104 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 356
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001934fa8e8 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 116
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001da1c48cc _pthread_wqthread + 216
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001da1cb77c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001da1cb774 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001da1cb774 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x000000016f559ff0   x5: 0x000000016f55a5a0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x00000000000dab00
    x8: 0x00000000000005b9   x9: 0xb08acf1d630ebb4e  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x0000000000000003
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000010
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000001010c38c0  x18: 0x00000001070ad630  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000407  x21: 0x00000001010c39a0  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x0000000002ffffff  x25: 0x00000001010c39a0  x26: 0x00000000000020ff  x27: 0x0000000000000104
   x28: 0x0000000283a0cf00   fp: 0x000000016f55a500   lr: 0x00000001da1c3c74
    sp: 0x000000016f55a4e0   pc: 0x00000001bf1a998c cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

Comment: You are getting an assertion exception in good order but you are not showing us what the assertion actually  says.

Comment: I have added all the crash logs now. Anything more that could help?

Comment: Mmm, I was expecting to see an actual message, in English words, saying what the exception is. I guess they didn't include that information...? — It's obvious where this must be happening (in your ProjectManager `importPhoto13`); could we see the actual code?

Comment: Sure: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cv43pq0bnr3wt49/crash.png?dl=0

Comment: Actually it would be better to copy and paste the code into the question...? Hard to read as an image. — So I presume you're sure you have the necessary photo library authorization? — Also I notice that the docs say "This method ignores the deliveryMode option"; I wouldn't expect to crash, but that does suggest that your `deliveryMode` setting is pointless...

Comment: You are right about the delivery mode.  I handle the authorization to photos, I believe correctly. 
The biggest problem is that I can't reproduce it, it doesn't happen in any of my ios 14.0.1 devices with iCloud on or off. I'm sorry for the code as an image, I wanted also to show you where the crash happens. (the line where the exception happens) 
Could this be synchronous vs asynchronous delivery? Doesn't this crash clearly show that the problem is on Apple's code? I have, of course, already asked for technical support :(  In any case, very much appreciated that you looked at it!

Comment: You didn’t ask for synchronous so this is asynchronous delivery. Nothing wrong with that. You could take a long time to get a result if this is a cloud image and the network is down (Apple always stress tests for no-network conditions), but I wouldn’t expect a crash; we should fail in good order.

Comment: I have submitted a bug report with their crash log and waiting for their technical support (also asked the same on the Developer forum, by now, probably nothing more than to wait,, Thanks a lot!